# Configuring Pantheios logging library

Tags: logging, pantheios

Is it possible to configure Pantheios logging library from outside
 such as from xml or properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the moment.

The TODO.txt file in the distribution lists a v1.2 item as be.loader, which I think is a dynamic back-end loader. It may be that there's something already developed, but not yet released - perhaps you can [contact the project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pantheios/forums/forum/475313).